# VBA function does not return dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba, return-value, dynamic-arrays, excel-365

I am using Excel365. Below function is intended to have SumProduct work with arrays that contain empty cells generated by a formula - when the result of the formula is "", SumProduct has problems with dealing with the empty cell / with the underlying formula.

```vb
Public Function RealDate(Zelle As Range) As Variant
' Returns the corresponding array of dates as long as the cell contains a valid date
' Returns 1.1.1900 for all the cells with invalid formats or dates

    Dim c As Range
    Dim b As Boolean, i As Integer, MinDate As Date
    Dim outputArray As Variant

    MinDate = "1.1.1900"                        ' This should be the value 0 in integers
    ReDim outputArray(1 To Zelle.Count)
    On Error GoTo Continue

    i = 0
    For Each c In Zelle.Cells
        i = i + 1
        outputArray(i) = MinDate
        b = IsDate(c.Value) And (year(c.Value) >= 1900) And (Day(c.Value) > 0)
        If b Then outputArray(i) = c.Value
    Continue:
        MsgBox outputArray(i)
        Next c
 
    RealDate = outputArray
    ' Unfortunately, this statement does not work - what is returned is a vector of mainly integer 0 or 01.01.1900

End Function
```

The trouble is the following:

[image: Function returns empty dates]

that is either 01.01.1900 or 00.01.1900, although in the message box all the dates for outputArray are given correctly, that is 01.01.90, 31.01.13, 14.01.14, 29.08.23. The size of the dynamic array is 4 (and that is correct).

It seems like RealDate does not take over the correct values from outputArray - why ???

I am expecting the function RealDate to return the values correctly stored in outputArray.

What did I try: The funny thing is that the results depend on the last line
RealDate = OutputArray.
For example, when I return
RealDate = VSTACK(outputArray)
the function returns 3x #Value, and in the 4th row 00.01.1990

[image]

The same for RealDate(1) = outputArray(1)
In both cases, when calling the function, no MsgBox is shown any more

Comment: Your function, as shown, would spill to the right of the cell you entered it in, not down. There is no spilling on your screenshot at all.

Comment: 1-Jan-1900 returns 1 in my Excel (not zero)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create and return a two-dimensional array:

```vb
    MinDate = Cdate(1)      
    ReDim outputArray(1 To Zelle.Count, 1 To 1)
    On Error GoTo Continue

    i = 0
    For Each c In Zelle.Cells
        i = i + 1
        outputArray(i, 1) = MinDate
        b = IsDate(c.Value) And (Year(c.Value) >= 1900) And (Day(c.Value) > 0)
        If b Then outputArray(i, 1) = c.Value
```

Comment: @Martin: you should not edit the question to add a comment. Add a comment via the "Add comment" button.

Comment: Then you probably should read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thank you all very much for your support! In general your solution works, but two problems remain: The last date still reports a #Value-Error although given correctly in the MsgBox; and wrong dates like "*****" get substituted by 02.01.1900 instead of 01.01.1900

Comment: I can't reproduce the error regarding the last entry. But I i get 2.1.1900 as well for a non-date entry ... this is really strange. It looks like if VBA starts with 1 = 31.12.1899 --> CDate(1). But Excel itself returns 1.1.1900 (when formatting a 1 as date)

Comment: Copied the formula into a new field, and now it works for all the 4 entries. The 2.1.1990 is so strange because where in the world does Excel get this figure from - I mean, at the beginning all the fields are set to 01.01.1900, and the "*****" input should just be ignored, so the field value should remain at 01.01.1900 - AS INDICATED IN MSGBOX !

Comment: A 1 gets me, too, a 01.01.1900.

Comment: This details will not kill me, though, as I only need to check years with my SumProduct - statement. If you could find out, it would really give me some faith in Excel/VBA, but do not waste your time on that detail.